# Repository pattern with mvc without entity framework

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, design-patterns, repository-pattern

Is repository pattern with unit of work best fit for entity framework application?

I am creating a new asp.net mvc application and i want to use stored procedure (microsoft enterprise library) instead of Entity framework(or any other ORM).

So how can i use repository pattern with mvc application?

I have explored many tutorials but not getting expected result. Please suggest me better approach for n tier application.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to understand that "repository pattern" is just an idea to organize your code. I think you can still use it without any problem.

I just want to provide you an example of implementation using sql stored procedure: suppose you have to manage the classic table "Contacts".

You can create your UnitOfWork contract:

```
public interface IContactsRepository {
 void AddContact(Contact c);
 void RemoveContact(Contact c);
 void UpdateContact(Contact c);
 void Search(string keyword);
}
```

After, you can create your own implementation without using EF:

```
public sealed class SPContactsRepository : IContactsRepository {
 // Is just an exampl.e 
 public void AddContact(Contact c) {
   var sqlCommnad = new SqlCommand(this._connectionString);
   sqlCommand.CommandText = "dbo.AddContact";
   sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
   sqlCommand.AddParameter("Name", c.Name);
   sqlCommand.Connection.Open();
   sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

 }
}
```

Hope this can help!

Comment: could you give me some link that will help me?

Comment: Please see @Allan T response. It will complete the answer to your question

Answer (score 4):

So just to continue what Roberto already started, your controller in the MVC app will look like this:

```
public class ContactsController : Controller
{
    private readonly IContactsRepository _contactsRepo;

    public ContactsController(IContactsRepository repo)
    {
        _contactsRepo = repo;
    }
}
```

These pattern uses dependency injection(DI). There are several options for DI container. You can use Unity which is a Microsoft package that you can install via nuget package manager to your MVC web project. The install will create a `UnityConfig.cs` file in your `App_Start` folder. You can register the dependency as:

```
public static void RegisterComponents()
{
    var container = new UnityContainer();
    container.RegisterType<IContactsRepository, SPContactsRepository>();
}
```

And in your `Global.asax.cs` file inside `Application_Start()`, you initialize the container:

```
UnityConfig.RegisterComponents();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use EF, the DbContext is already your Unit of Work and the DbSet as your repository. Having said that, you should not create a repository that will add another layer of data abstraction. Instead, you can create, domain services.